# Cannot download Blend files from questions

Tags: support, blend-exchange

Anyone else having problems downloading example .Blend files from blend-exchange in posts?  I have tried a couple posts, and the download link to the example blend files leads me to a blank page.

Below is the specific post/link I'm having issues with at the moment.  The OP says he can download it.  Everyone else downloading it ok?  I have tried two browsers on two different computers.  Either I get a blank page (Firefox), or an error, this page doesn't exist (IE10).  I haven't tried at my home, only work, so maybe a firewall issue.

The Post:
[Cloth sim; Cloth Pin and Self Collision making very bad/weird behavior?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49694/cloth-sim-cloth-pin-and-self-collision-making-very-bad-weird-behavior/49695#49695)

The link to the file:
http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1151/

Thanks, just trying to get to the bottom of this so I can help this guy out!

Comment: This is self hosted by a community member. We are looking into it, thanks for the post.

Answer (score 6):

I'm the guy who wrote the code for blend-exchange and operates it. The issue has been resolved, thanks for posting this message so I could be notified.

The issue was caused by a crashed database due to a ram shortage on my server. This is usually caused by Denial of Service (DoS) attack on the server that hosts blend-exchange. I'm going to do an in-depth investigation as to why this crash occurred, and try to avoid repeat occurrences in the future.

Sorry for any inconvenience caused by unavailable files.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time and resources to provide this valuable service, and support it.  Damn DoS attacks are from the devil.